# Is there any way to get all the method's aliases in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Suppose I've got a class:

```
class MyClass
  def my_method
    # cool stuff
  end
  alias :my_method2 :method
end
```

And now I want to get all the aliases for method my_method without comparison with all the object methods.

Comment: Show all the relevant code. And how is alias  of `method` relevant to the question?

Comment: Why don't you want to compare with the other methods?

Comment: The relevant code is ActiveSupport:: Memoizable.memoize method. It doesn't works for aliased methods(don't actually know if it should, but I want it so in my project). Comparison is not a universal way here I think.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to do it without using comparisons. However, if you remove Object.methods you can limit the comparisons made:

```
def aliased?(x)
  (methods - Object.methods).each do |m|
    next if m.to_s == x.to_s
    return true if method(m.to_sym) == method(x.to_sym)
  end
  false
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a hack, but seems to work in 1.9.2 (but does not in 1.8 etc.):

```
 def is_alias obj, meth
   obj.method(meth).inspect =~ /#<Method:\s+(\w+)#(.+)>/
   $2 != meth.to_s
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass.instance_methods(false)` will give you just the instance methods defined for your class.  This is a good way to get rid of any ancestor methods.  In your case, the only methods that should show up are `my_method` and `my_method2`.